# BIOS POST problem

Tags: post, bios, motherboard

I have an ASUS P5Q SE2 motherboard with 2x 2GB DDR2. I recently added 1x 1GB RAM which is when my problems started.

I can hardly get my PC to boot. When I power it on, in most cases it restarts after about 10 seconds and then there is only a black screen. The fans keep spinning.

If I leave it powered off overnight with the BIOS battery out, in the morning it boots and I am asked to reset the system time. I load the BIOS defaults, set the time and start Windows, and the PC works normally; when I power it off, insert the BIOS battery again and power back on I get the black screen issue.

The last time I was able to successfully start Windows, I tried flashing the BIOS but the problem still persisted.

What can I do to fix this? I've had the problem for five days now.

Comment: Have you tried removing the extra RAM?

Comment: Even after removing all RAM - same problem, no beeps. Starts up, restarts, then black screen as a mentioned above.
If is a case when it will start - then it beeps, when I insert RAM it starts normally :)

Comment: Your bios battery may have died. If it provides the wrong voltage, the operation of the real time clock may be disrupted and your computer won't work.